Bootstrapping method

mediation_result <- mediate(mediator_model, outcome_model, treat = "transformational", mediator = "psych_needs", sims = 1000)
Error in [.data.frame(y.data, , treat) : undefined columns selected

help me with the error
Load necessary libraries
library(mediation)
Create a composite score for psychological needs
data$psych_needs <- rowMeans(data[, c("autonomy", "competence", "relatedness")], na.rm = TRUE)
Check the composite variable
print(head(data$psych_needs))
Ensure that the treatment variable is numeric
data$transformational <- as.numeric(data$transformational)
Fit the mediator model
mediator_model <- lm(psych_needs ~ transformational + transactional + autonomy_supportive + Gender + AgeGroup + JobLevel, data = data)
Fit the outcome model
outcome_model <- lm(quiet_quitting ~ psych_needs + Gender + AgeGroup + JobLevel, data = data)
Perform mediation analysis
mediation_result <- mediate(mediator_model, outcome_model, treat = "transformational", mediator = "psych_needs", sims = 1000)
View the summary of the mediation result
summary(mediation_result)
I am trying to perform bootstrap method for mediation analysis
